# Write access to all unix accounts on mounted NFS drive

Tags: linux, nfs

We have mounted a directory from SERVER A to SERVER B using NFS. All unix accounts on Server B should be able to write to the mounted directory, also overwrite files created by accounts in Server B. exports file already has rw permission. Unix account in serverB is not able to write into the mounted nfs directory.  How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: How is authentication performed on the two machines?

Comment: As the nfs directory is permanently mounted there would be no authentication between 2 machines. The mount happens through private IP

Comment: Sorry, ambiguous question - how is user authentication performed on the two machines?

Comment: User authentication is ssh-password based. But in this case I would like to bypass any means of authentication.

Comment: do hostA and hostB have same /etc/passwd ?

Comment: No, It is not the same UID and GID will be common for only few users not all of them.

Comment: I think what you need here is the `all_squash` NFS mount option which maps all requests to your NFS mount to the anonymous user and group ID. Then you can use the `anonuid` and `anongid` mount options to control which these two IDs are for the mount point. Then all that is left is to make sure the initial mount point is this user and group. Whichever user and group you choose as the anonymous ones must be the same on both machines.

Comment: I already have all_squash set in nfs. Do you mean I have to map uid and gid for users in both servers. But, the users in hostA are different from hostB

Comment: Well using all_squash mean all request to the NFS server (`ServerB`) are made as the anonymous user, so if the directory you are mounting is owned by that anonymous user all people who use the NFS mount will be able to create/modify/delete all files.

Comment: What is the issue you're trying to resolve?

Comment: Any Unix account on serverB should be able to write to the mounted nfs directory.

Comment: Where in your question does it say that they can't do this? Please EDIT your question to provide a proper explanation of what's you're trying to achieve and what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD, in `/etc/exports` you can do this:

```
/serverADir -mapall=allnfsusers:allnfsusers ...IP or server...
```

Now create the `allnfsusers` user account and set the permissions `chown -R allnfsusers:allnfsusers /serverADir`.